# How to trigger a javascript event base on an old input in Laravel 4 ?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

**How to trigger a javascript event base on an old input in Laravel 4 ?**

```
       The script work perfectly when select from dropdown menu.
```

In Laravel 4, in one of my Edit view, I tried to Edit some logistics information. 
Base on my dropdown menu, the layout and behavior of my form will be slightly different.

Again, the script **work** perfectly when **selected** from dropdown menu.

I loaded the whole form base on old inputs.Everything works great !
Only the script doesn't seem to run base on an old inputs that were loaded.

The trigger won't change unless, I started to select something from my **payment_method** list, then thing started to work again.

**QUESTION**

Is there away to load the script base on an  old input in Laravel 4?

**Form Details :**

**Dropdown Menu** id = payment_method

- receiver paid
- shipper paid

**Dropdown Menu** id = shipping_carrier
 - Fedex
 - DHL

**Input Field** id = shipping_number __________________

**Goal:**

if user select **shipper paid**

1. disable shipping_carrier
2. hide() my shipping number input

Else,

1. enable the shipping_carrier
2. enable shipping number input (required)

**CODE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#note').hide();

    $("#payment_method").change(function() {


        console.log($("#payment_method option:selected").val());



        if ($("#payment_method option:selected").val() == 2) {
            $('#shipping_carrier').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#shipping_carrier').val(1);
            $('#shipping_number').hide();
            $('#note').show();
            $('.shipping_carrier').hide();
        } else {
            $('#shipping_carrier').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#shipping_number').show();
            $('#note').hide();
        }
    });


})
```

Part of my Edit Form in blade

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label required  " for="payment_method">Payment Method </label>

    <div class=" col-sm-7 form-group float-label-control">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-dollar"></i>
            </span>
             {{Form::select('payment_method', array('1' => 'Receiver Paid', '2' => 'Shipper Paid'), isset($distributor->payment_method ) ? $distributor->payment_method  : 'Receiver Paid', array('id' => 'payment_method')); }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group ">
    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label required  " for="shipping_carrier">Shipping Carrier </label>

    <div class=" col-sm-7 form-group float-label-control">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
            </span>
             {{Form::select('shipping_carrier', array('FedEx' => 'FedEx', 'UPS' => 'UPS', 'DHL' => 'DHL', 'Nippon Express' => 'Nippon Express'), isset($distributor->shipping_carrier ) ? $distributor->shipping_carrier  : 'Receiver Paid', array('id' => 'shipping_carrier')); }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<span value="" name="note" id="note"> My Company will paid for the shipping cost and bill to receiver. </span>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label "> </label>
    <div class="col-sm-7 form-group float-label-control ">
        <span class="input-icon input-icon-right">
             {{Form::text('shipping_number', isset($distributor->shipping_number ) ? $distributor->shipping_number  : 'Receiver Paid', array('id' => 'shipping_number','placeholder'=>'Carrier Acct#')); }}
             {{ $errors->first('shipping_number','<a title=":message" class="btn btn-white btn-pink btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove "></span> :message </a>') }}

        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Suport Documents(Images):**

1. [Receiver Paid Selected](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/ii_149bf86ded5f38c4.png)
2. [Shipper Paid Selected](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/ii_149bf87a9d3299aa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#note').hide();

    $("#payment_method").change(function() {


        console.log($("#payment_method option:selected").val());



        if ($("#payment_method option:selected").val() == 2) {
            $('#shipping_carrier').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#shipping_carrier').val(1);
            $('#shipping_number').hide();
            $('#note').show();
            $('#shipping_carrier').hide();
            $('#shiping_carrier_label').hide();





        } else {
            $('#shipping_carrier').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#shipping_number').show();
            $('#note').hide();
            $('#shiping_carrier_label').show();
            $('#shipping_carrier').show();
        }
    }).trigger('change');                                   // Modified this line


})
```

just simply append

### .trigger('change')

to the end of the handler assignment.It's work perfectly, now.